# Custom method or association for chained model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

I have three models : `User`, `Product` and `Transaction`.

Here are the associations :

**app/models/transaction.rb**

```rb
# A transaction has a `current` boolean that is true when the transaction is currently happening, and nil else.

belongs_to :seeker, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "seeker_id"
belongs_to :product
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```rb
has_many :owned_products, class_name: "Product",
                          foreign_key: "owner_id",
                          dependent: :destroy
has_many :transactions, foreign_key: "seeker_id",
                        dependent: :destroy
has_many :requested_products, through: :transactions, source: :product
has_many :active_transactions, -> { where current: true },
                               class_name: 'Transaction',
                               foreign_key: "seeker_id"
has_many :borrowed_products, through: :active_transactions, source: :product
```

**app/models/product.rb**

```rb
belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User",
                   foreign_key: "owner_id"
has_many :transactions, dependent: :destroy
has_many :seekers, through: :transactions,
                     source: :seeker  
has_one :active_transaction, -> { where current: true },
                             class_name: 'Transaction'
has_one :borrower, through: :active_transaction,
                            source: :seeker
```

I want to create a method that allows me to do the following :

```rb
user.owned_products.available # returns every product owned by the user that has a transaction with current:true.
user.owned_products.lended # returns every product owned by the user that has no transaction with current.true
```

Is this possible ? If not, I would do an association link like `user.available_products` and `user.lended_products` but I don't know how, because I must use conditions from both models in order to make an association in a third, like this :

**app/models/user.rb**

```rb
has_many :available_products, -> { where borrower: nil },
                              class_name: "Product",
                              foreign_key: "owner_id"
```

And I get this error message :

```rb
ActionView::Template::Error:
   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: products.borrower: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."owner_id" = ? AND "products"."borrower" IS NULL
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a scope

```
scope :available, where(:current => true).joins(:transactions)
```

now you can say

```
user.owned_products.available
```

This is not tested. But this will give you an idea of how to go ahead.

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) is a reference for scopes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry but it doesn't work :-(
I have already read the rails guide on scopes, but the examples are few, and I don't understand quite well. Otherwise, do you think I should delete some of my `has_many` associations in order to replace them by `scopes` ?